# access web services from WSDL link java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, ebay-api

I am trying to access web services that are defined in WSDL by giving the url of the WSDL. The specific case I am working on is the ebay "FindingService".

After parsing the WSDL, I search for the service I am looking for (for example "FindingService"). Next, I want to be able to use that service (send keywords and get results) through some sort of client. I looked around and found the following code that I tried to modify to use it for my example. Since I am still new to WSDL, I am not sure of how to adapt it and I keep getting the error: Undefined port type: {http://WSDL/}face

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;


public class client{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/findingservice.wsdl");

        //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
    //2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
        QName qname = new QName("http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services", "FindingService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);


        face hello = service.getPort(face.class);

       System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("test"));

    }

}
```

the second class is:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

//Service Endpoint Interface
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface face{

    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);

}
```

the third class is:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "face")
public class endp implements face{

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
        return "Hello World JAX-WS " + name;
    }

}
```

I'd be thankful if I can get some guidance. Is it possible to access services like that or do I have to use the ebay API (with keys etc..) ?

Comment: I think your URL should point to the deployed service and NOT the WSDL. The WSDL should have been used for generating the client and shouldn't be used in the code unless you are using a dynamic client.

Comment: This is actually what I'm trying to do. I would like the program to work for different wsdl not only one, which is why I'm trying to avoid generating the client using wsdl ! is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is just a contract between the client and the server.

The best solution is not parse the WSDL in runtime and try to call the actions. You probably want to call these actions to do something useful. Ex: find all user Ebay orders.

Each of these actions can have complex inputs and outputs. The best solution to work with SOAP webservices in Java is usually generate code based in the WSDL, so you will have a full working client without too much work.

I can recommend these APIs:

JAX-WS:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Spring-WS:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Axis 2:
https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html

Comment: Thanks Jonas for the answer. I've looked through the links and searched a little more and now I realized that I might have been missing something. What I'm trying to do is look for web services in a public UDDI (based on keywords entered by the user) and after finding the service, consume it. That's making me more confused as I cannot find any source that explains how to write a Java code to do that !! would you have any idea of how this can be done ?